# SQLAlchemy joining tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store history information for each time a user does certain actions. As the history information will be the same for multiple tables (eg store - imported data from file x), I want to keep the history data in a separate table and store the id of relevant history items in other tables. The issue I am having is that not every table will have their history list added to every time time history is changed- so storing a ForeignKey for every table (tens of tables) in History doesn't look to be the right approach.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import DateTime, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import ForeignKey

class TableA(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tablea'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)
    data = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    history = relationship("History")

class TableB(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tableb'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)
    data = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    history = relationship("History")

class TableC(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tablec'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)
    data = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    history = relationship("History")

class History(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'history'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable = False)
    details = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    version = Column(String(), nullable=True)
    tablea_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tablea.id'))
    tableb_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tableb.id'))
    tablec_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('tablec.id'))

class Base(object):

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return str(cls.__name__)
    create_date = Column(DateTime, default=func.now()) 

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)
```

The only way I can work out how to do this is store a list of history id's in each of TableA,B,C as a string. Then use JSON to decode the string into a python list. But this approach is tedious and error prone. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a better way, please read [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) examples. In particular, [`discriminator_on_association`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/_modules/examples/generic_associations/discriminator_on_association.html) or a [`generic_fk`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html) examples should fit your requirements.

Comment: @van Thanks for that. I exactly copied the discriminator example, substituting history(ies) for address(es). My case is a bit different as, unlike unique addresses, there will be history objects that are exactly the same, but referenced by multiple tables. Also I want to append to a history 'list' rather than write all in one go as per the example. I created history so I can store reference in multiple tables, but then tablea.histories = [self.history] session.add(tablea) doesn't allow me to append. I'll look at generic_fk but the event listener looks a bit odd.